# Delay on call to MATLAB function

Tags: c++, matlab

I call a MATLAB function (dll) from my C++ code. This function gets an array as a parameter.
Function does some calculation on each member of array. 
I did two tests.
For the first time I called this function with an array with 24 elements.
For the second time I called this function three times with 8 elements.
The second test took twice more time.
Why ?
Does enter into MATLAB function and exit from it take a lot of time ?
If yes, why ?

Comment: Are these results consistent? Can you reproduce them?

Answer (score 2):

What you've noticed is that it costs a fair amount of time to call into a MEX function. Consider the minimum that Matlab has to do:

1. Scan the Matlab path to make sure that the function maps to the MEX file (and that the MEX file hasn't changed)
2. Load the MEX function from its DLL or shared library, and then resolve its `mexFunction` symbol.
3. Allocate arrays of input and output parameters, and initialize them
4. Call your function
5. Look for and free any temporary variables that your MEX function loaded
6. Free the arrays of input and output parameters

In theory, Matlab can use caching to avoid the first two steps.  I'm not sure if it does, though.  None of the subsequent steps can be skipped, or even really optimized by the Matlab interpreter (or its JIT compiler).  Basically, if your calculation is fast, then you'll spend a lot more time calling the MEX function than actually running it.

You've already hit on the way to maximize MEX performance, which is to have the MEX function do as much as possible with each call.

In addition to having it work on as much data as you can on each call, you should also push any simple outer loops into the MEX function.  Simple loops are easy to implement in MEX functions.  They're also faster than loops in Matlab (even JIT-compiled Matlab), and avoid the cost of repeatedly calling the MEX function.

You can also see if judicious use of the [`mexLock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexlock.html) function will help.  You should provide some way to unlock the MEX function with [`mexUnlock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexunlock.html), or you may start leaking memory, and will also have to restart your Matlab session every time you change the MEX function.